# Performing outer join on temporal-like sql tables - How to get every temporal state?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, temporal

I have 2 SQL tables (E1, E2) that are related together with a parent-child relation (E1 is parent).
Every time an update is performed on a record a new record is created (temporal / historization).

I would like to get, using a left join query (child has not to exist), all the different states of their relation within the life time of the records

```
Sample E1:
Id     StartDate     EndDate       Value
----------------------------------------------------
1      2017-11-01    2017-11-05    Initial E1 (Day 1)
1      2017-11-05    2017-11-14    E1 (update Day 5)
1      2017-11-14    9999-12-31    E1 (Update Day 14)

Sample E2:
Id     StartDate     EndDate       Value                 E1_Id
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      2017-11-03    2017-11-12    Initial E2 (Day 3)    1
1      2017-11-12    9999-12-31    E2 (Day 12)           1
```

I was (naively) expecting to get each state of the relation using a left join query where the “ON” combines the ID and the StartDate and EndDate. 
However, I do not get any row for the timeslot where the child does not exist (I expect a record for the slot between 1st and 3rd of November).

```
select *
from e1
left join e2 on  e1.id = e2.E1_Id 
and e1.StartDate < e2.EndDate 
and e1.EndDate >= e2.StartDate


Id  StartDate   EndDate Value                       Id  StartDate   EndDate Value                 E1_Id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2017-11-01  2017-11-05  Initial  E1    (Day 1)  1   2017-11-03  2017-11-12  Initial E2 (Day 3)        1  temporal validity: 3-5 nov
1   2017-11-05  2017-11-14  E1 (update Day 5)          1    2017-11-03  2017-11-12  Initial E2 (Day 3)  1    temporal validity: 5-12 nov
1   2017-11-05  2017-11-14  E1 (update Day 5)          1    2017-11-12  9999-12-31  E2 (Day 12)        1     temporal validity: 12-14 nov
1   2017-11-14  9999-12-31  E1 (Update Day 14)         1    2017-11-12  9999-12-31  E2 (Day 12)        1     temporal validity: from 14 nov


As the first 1 records, I was expecting this extra record
Id  StartDate   EndDate Value                       Id  StartDate   EndDate Value                 E1_Id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2017-11-01  2017-11-03  Initial  E1    (Day 1)  1   <Null>  <NULL>      <NULL>          <NULL>   temporal validity: 1-3 nov.
…..
```

[Edited the expected endate (was nov 5 and must be nov 3)].
The idea is to track in the output query every change we have in the relation of the parent-child

Does anyone has an idea to get the  information correctly?

Thanks,
José

Comment: Why do you say "I expect a record for the slot between 1st and 3rd of November"....Where would the record come from?

Comment: Adding a sample output of your perfect desired results would also be helpful

Comment: The `left join` ensures that all records from `E1` are listed, and this is the case, so I don't understand why you think something is missing.

Comment: @grantly: When I say that I expect a record for the date between 1st and 3rd of November, I mean that between these 2 dates, the parent had no child. Therefore, I would expect the 1st output of the query to be a line with only the parent information and a set of null for the child information.

Comment: ...And between those dates - does a parent actually exist (between 1st and 3rd of November)?

Comment: @trincot: Yes, I agree. However, I'm expecting to somehow get as the first resulting record the case where the parent (E1) exists but not the child (1st to 3rd of November).

Comment: Add a sample of the output you want to see...  I can't really understand your written instructions properly

Comment: @Grantly:
Yes, if you look at the record history of E1, the parent has been created november the 1st and had a first modification on the 5th. The child was only created on the 3rd and later modified on the 12th.

Comment: As soon as the outer join results in a record match in E2, there will not be the virtual record with `null`s in your output. That is how outer joins work. According to your definition of the relation, *every* record in the E1 sample has at least one child, so there will not be `null`s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are thinking of two types of children:

- Those in E2 that contain the StartDate of the E1 record, and
- Those in E2 that contain the EndDate of the E1 record

And you want to see a record for both situations, with possibly `null` values when that *particular* child does not exist.

In that case you could create two separate queries for these two different cases, and then take the union of the results:

```
select    * 
from      e1 
left join e2 
       on e1.id = e2.E1_Id 
      and e1.StartDate between e2.StartDate and e2.EndDate
union
select    * 
from      e1 
left join e2 
       on e1.id = e2.E1_Id 
      and e1.EndDate between e2.StartDate and e2.EndDate
where     e1.EndDate < '9999-12-31'
order by 2, 6;
```

The last condition on the special date is probably what you want, because that date really seems to mean "infinity", so it should not be contained in any period. But try also the query without that condition to see what you get from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. According to my question, it fully does the trick!

 However, I just seen that I had a mistake in my first record expectation. In fact, the "end date" for the first record should be november 3 (The second record starts at november 3)